# watir - ruby code "undefined method present? pr exist"

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require "watir"

    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome,:switches => %w[--disable-notifications]
    i=0;
    begin

    #TODO logining to the facebook
    browser.goto 'linkedin.com'
    browser.text_field(:id => 'login-email').set 'ananthragavendra@gmail.com'
    browser.text_field(:id => 'login-password').set 'ru09ec32'
    browser.button(type: 'submit').click

    puts '**** linkedin logged in ****'

    sea = browser.div(:class => 'nav-search-bar')
    puts sea
    if sea.exits?
    browser.div(:class => 'nav-search-bar').click
    browser.div(:class => 'type-ahead-input-container').text_field.set 'wipro'
    browser.button(:class => 'nav-search-button').click
    puts '**** searched, the results for wipro is shown '
    else
    puts 'div not present'
    end


    side = browser.div(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail')
    puts side
    if side.present?
    puts 'div present'
    side1 = browser.divs(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail')
    else
    puts 'div not present'
    end



    #TODO exception handling
    rescue Exception => e
    p "Error Found..... #{e.message}"
    end
```

The error is thrown while executing the above simply, I am able to found the div in real time but I am unable to check the div using if commands, I have also tried some codes like exists.

Comment: Can you remove the extraneous code and show the minimum repeatable code to get the error? Can you then provide a stack trace without rescuing the exception in your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, this line `if sea.exits?` is wrong, change this to `if sea.exists?`

And your code is perfect, but very minute changes require to effectuate the WATIR's predefined wait statement.

You used this statement

```
side = browser.div(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail')
```

If you write this way, then WATIR's predefined wait doesn't work because the method which you are going to call upon `Watir::Div` object is where four checking happens,

for an example, if you call

```
browser.div(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail').click
```

then these four following checking will happen

```
1)exist?
2)enabled?
3)present?
4)writable?
```

But if you don't call any function as I have shown then it will NOT return the element because statement is getting executed even before element is loaded, So as a result of that side.present? is false and it gives you the result that `div not present`

So change your code in the following way

```
browser.div(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail').click
  side = browser.div(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail')
  puts side
  if side.present?
    puts 'div present'
    side1 = browser.divs(:class => 'right-rail search-right-rail')
  else
    puts 'div not present'
  end
```

Now your code will work perfectly. present method will return true for you.

Comment: This isn't quite true. Watir lazy loads the elements, so you can define an element without it looking for anything. You're right that when doing a `#click` you get those 4 checks (technically they are: `#exist?`, `#visible?`, `#enabled?`, and `#writeable?`), but when he calls `if side.present?` it is still checking `#exist?` & `#visible?`. A more important distinction is when using `#click` Watir will actually wait for those conditions to be met, where just calling `#present?` won't. But regardless, the error he is reporting has nothing to do with these things.

Comment: I know of this, yes it waits for exist and rest of the operation while it tries through click or any other function and it doesn't wait if I directly write `if b.div.exists?`, I know of this very clearly. I executed the whole program I don't have that error other than what I have mentioned, So including what I said surely resolve the problem. You said 'watir lazy loads the element' but it's not loading when it reaches to that particular code. That's what I included `click` function there just to wait until that particular element present.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have got the answer from the above

Comment: @ananthraj Thanks for quick reply :)

Answer (score -1):

`present?` is added to `Object` by Rails. So if you are outside of Rails, you probably mean: `!side.nil?`

Comment: The `Watir::Element` class also has a `#present?` method, which is what he is trying to use.

Comment: What's the exact error? It normally says something like "undefined method present? for ObjectInstance" and I'm wondering what's ObjectInstance in this case. Please include the line that it's giving you the error too.